# How do I delete newlines within quotes when using the fireplace plugin for vim?

Tags: vim, clojure

I'm trying to learn Clojure while using the fireplace plugin for vim but am completely frustrated by the inability to delete certain things. For example

```
(
```

cannot be deleted as far as I can tell (If you manage to delete the right parens you end up with this stuck in the program. You can't delete it and you can't type a new right parens) Even more:

```
"first line
       more on another line"
```

The second line cannot be deleted when fireplace is enabled. Is this plugin just broken or am I missing something?

Comment: You might need to rediagnose this problem. I have always used fireplace.vim together with surround.vim without any issues, and have no problems doing the editing operations that you can’t seem to do.

Answer (score 0):

...and, I figured it out. [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) doesn't work with fireplace. When I removed that plugin [fireplace](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace) began to act sanely.